# Programmatically logging in customer doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.7, login, programmatically

I'm using this code to login a customer programmatically:

```
<?php
require_once ("app/Mage.php");    

Mage::app('default');

// Init a Magento session. This is super ultra important
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
// We get an instance of the customer model for the actual website
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

// Load the client with the appropriate email
$email = "user@email.com";
$customer->loadByEmail($email);

// Get a customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

// Login an check the customer by his database userId
if ($session->loginById($customer->getId())) {
    echo '<div>Succesfull loginById</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div>Error in loginById</div>';
}

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo '<div>Welcome</div>';
} else {
    echo '<div>Denied</div>';
}
```

But it's not working, the result I'm getting in the browser is:

> Succesfull loginById
>
> Denied

What could be the issue here?

---

EDIT

Some new information: I've tried this script on a different shop we have running and it works perfectly there. Why would it work on one but not the other?

---

EDIT 2

More troubleshooting has resulted in the conclusion that `$session->getId()` returns `NULL` while it should return an actual ID. Still no idea why this shop doesn't return a session id while the other one does.

Comment: Where you using this code?

Comment: In a PHP script outside of Magento, I've included `app/Mage.php` in the script.

Comment: Please update the full code

Comment: Updated, added the require statement

Comment: @Rias have checked your code and looks perfectly fine

Comment: @Rias .. Have you tried in other browsers?. It may be browser cache issue

Comment: @MineshPatel Then why does it give "Denied" on `$session->isLoggedIn()`?


@vinothavn Yes I've checked in different browsers

Comment: Does `$customer->getId()` return a value before you attempt the login?

Comment: @MichaelO'Loughlin Yes, it returns a correct ID

Comment: I tried this script on a different shop and it worked, why would it work on one but not the other?

Comment: The `isLoggedIn()` method may be rewritten. I'd use xDebug to step through the `isLoggedIn()` method or try outputting `$session->getId()`.  `isLoggedIn()` checks the ID is located in the database with `Mage::getResourceSingleton('customer/customer')->checkCustomerId($id)` which could also be failing for some strange reason.

Comment: @MichaelO'Loughlin Okay it seems like the session isn't being created successfully `$session->getId()` returns `NULL`, on the other shop it returns a number.

Comment: Maybe the account is accosted with a different website ID?

Comment: @MichaelO'Loughlin We thought so too at a point but we've double and triple checked and the customer data is all correct. The cookie (frontend) also doesn't get created but that might just be a result of the session not working.

Comment: Does the customer need to confirm the account before it becomes active? In the customer session model you can see that it will check if confirmation is required. If the account is not confirmed, it will log out. Screenshot 1: http://cloud.plugin.company/screenshots/Screenshot_at_20-29-33.png Screenshot 2: http://cloud.plugin.company/screenshots/Screenshot_at_20-31-46.png

Comment: @MilanSimek That was indeed the issue! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Rias My pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Where `$customer` is a loaded instance of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`

Comment: Adding this doesn't really seem to change anything.

Comment: setCustomerAsLoggedIn() is already available in loginById() function

Comment: Code works for me. `loginById()` loads the customer model again so you should go with `setCustomerAsLoggedIn()` anyway. 

Ensure your email has an active account.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once ("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);

$websiteId = 1;
Mage::run('store_view_code', 'store');
Mage::init($websiteId, 'website');

$email = 'foo@bar.com';

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

if ($customer->getId()) {
    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

    $url = 'http://www.domain.com/test';
    $session->setAfterAuthUrl($url);
    header('Location: ' . $session->getAfterAuthUrl());
    exit();
}
```