# Magento where do I get customer salt value used

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to find what salt value, which is used to store password in customer_entity table.

Comment: Check this table customer_entity_varchar

Comment: @LearningMagento I no need password encrypted value, I need the salt value which is used to encrypt and store it

Comment: @arun-jamhub what do you want and why ?

Comment: @MineshPatel I need for an external application to allow customer to login  using the same table

Comment: You can login customer programmatic

Comment: @arun-jamhub check this [programmatically-logging-in-customer-doesnt-work](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85587/programmatically-logging-in-customer-doesnt-work/85589#85589)

Comment: @MineshPatel It worked, please check below how I solved. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it after a long search, password itself have salt value stored at last two digits.

```
SELECT * FROM customer_entity z, customer_entity_varchar b where z.email  = 'xxx@gmail.com' and z.entity_id = b.entity_id and b.attribute_id = 4  and b.value = concat(concat(md5(concat(right(b.value,2),'test123')),":"),right(b.value,2))
```